How to get VSCode's Love2D Support extension to recognize my path?
I installed Love2D and the Love2D Support extension for VS Code. I can run Love2D from the command line ($ love). In addition, $ which love provides the app's path (usr/bin/love). Typing $ usr/bin/love runs the app and I can see it in my file explorer.
Adding the path to the Love2D extension and running an app (Alt-L)
gives me an error:

Path specified in pixelbyte.love2d.path
'/usr/bin/love' does not exist. Check your settings.

Here's the weirdest part (to me): If I activate the terminal within VS Code and type
sh-5.2$ which love
I get the message:
Path specified in pixelbyte.love2d.path '/usr/bin/love' does not exist. Check your settings.

The which command should include the root path as /usr/bin/love, if you didn't see it, the path is relative to your current directory.

The problem turned out to be because I installed VS Code through flatpak. I solved it by uninstalling the app, and then reinstalling as a .deb file through https://code.visualstudio.com.
